# ¿Como puedo ejecutar una función en segundo plano en python?

Tags: python, linux, http

tengo una función en python que se encarga de activar un servidor utilizando los modulos http.server y socketserver, esta función se ejecuta dentro de otra función, y después de que se ejecuta el server todavía hay codigo que falta por ejecutarse, por lo tanto, no quiero que se quede congelada la consola cuando se ejecuta el server, ¿Hay alguna forma de evitar eso? También investigué un poco y probé con el modulo de os.devnull pero aun sigue con el mismo problema, no se si lo habré hecho mal, este es mi código:

```
def server():
port = random.randint(1,65535)      
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
try:
    s.connect(('10.255.255.255', 1))
    IP = s.getsockname()[0]
    dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'output')
    os.chdir(dir)

    Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
    httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", port), Handler)
    devnull = open(os.devnull, 'wb')
    t = httpd.serve_forever()   
    subprocess.call(t, stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)
    print("\nServer HTTP: http://" + IP + ":" + port)        
except:
    IP = '127.0.0.1'
finally:
    s.close()
return IP
```

Y esta es una foto de como se queda congelado.

[image: esta es una foto de como se queda congelado.]

Si alguien sabe como solucionarlo favor de ayudarme con este problema, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: En esa función se congela el programa y el código no ejecuta una funcion que sigue?, no estoy muy familiarizado con eso pero quizas deberias investigar hilos para ejecutar 2 códigos a la vez

Comment: El código funciona bien, el server se ejecuta correctamente, lo que quiero hacer es que no se vea el trafico del server en la terminal, que lo omita, ya que después de que se ejecuta el server aún hay más código por ejecutarse

Comment: En la imagen que puse no se ve el trafico porque la función os.devnull logra omitirlo, pero aún así se queda congelado en la terminal, el server sigue en escucha, lo que quiero es que permanezca en segunda plano y me permita seguir ejecutando código después de que se ejecute el server

Comment: En bash para lograr esto tengo entendido que es: python -m SimpleHTTPServer port > /dev/null 2>&1 &, por eso también investigué sobre el modulo de os.devnull

Answer (score 2):

De acuerdo a la información de stackoverflow en Ingles primero para el caso hipotetico definimos la función que va a correr en segundo plano:

```py
def function_that_downloads(my_args):
    # do some long download here
```

Luego importamos la utilidad que nos permitira correr la función en un nuevo hilo de procesos:

```
import threading
def my_inline_function(some_args):
    # do some stuff
    download_thread = threading.Thread(target=function_that_downloads, args=some_args)
    download_thread.start()
    # continue doing stuff
```

Para chequear si el hilo ha finalizado antes de hacer alguna acción que se requiera simplemente verificamos si el proceso esta vivo o no llamando la función `isAlive()` como sigue:

```py
download_thread.isAlive()
```

Tu código como tiene un valor de retorno se tendría que utilizar una cola donde se envíe el dato de retorno y quedaría así:

```py
import queue
import threading
import random
import socket

def server(q):
    port = random.randint(1, 65535)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    try:
        s.connect(('10.255.255.255', 1))
        IP = s.getsockname()[0]
        dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'output')
        os.chdir(dir)
        Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
        httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(('', port), Handler)
        devnull = open(os.devnull, 'wb')
        t = httpd.serve_forever()
        subprocess.call(t, stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)
        print '\nServer HTTP: http://' + IP + ':' + port
    except:
        IP = '127.0.0.1'
    finally:
        s.close()
    q.put(IP) #Este es nuestro return pero utilizando colas


q = queue.Queue()
download_thread = threading.Thread(target=server, args=(q, ))
download_thread.start()
while download_thread.isAlive():
    print 'Procesando '
print("Proceso finalizado")
print("IP:",q.get()) #aqui leemos el valor que se escribio en cola
```

- Conoce mas acerca de Hilos: [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168508/background-function-in-python).
- Conoce mas acerca de cola para el valor de retorno:
  [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577233/threading-in-python-retrieve-return-value-when-using-target)

Comment: Y como quedaría al acomodarlo con mi función? no conozco bien ese módulo

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, he agregado una libería más porque tienes un valor de retorno que hay que obtener al finalizar la función. Eso se logra con una cola que reciba el dato y sea actualizada para cuando se recibe la señal de finalización se pueda leer la cola y el dato que se puso en ella (que es el return $IP).